# ER modelling film actor

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, entity-relationship

I want to design a database schema for a movie and tv series database using the E-R model and design tables accordingly using the relationship model. The necessary information is given below :

Entities : Movie, Actors, TV series.
A TV series or a movie must have an actor. An actor can act in both.
Assume columns accordingly and mention primary keys, weak and strong entities.

This is the question I tried to solve. I have few doubt related to this.

1. **First Method**

   - Actor

     - actorID (PK)
     - actorName
   - Movies

     - actorID (FK:Actor) (PK)
     - movieID
     - movieName
     - movieGenre
   - TVSeries

     - actorID (FK:Actor) (PK)
     - tvsID
     - tvsName
     - tvsGenre

In this, model will have above three tables with given attributes. It maintains the criteria that each tv series or movie must have an actor and an actor can act in both. But If a movie has three/four actor then we have to enter movieName,movieGenre for same movieID. It is repetition of information and I do not want that.

2. **Second Method**

   - Actor

     - actorID (PK)
     - actorName
   - Movies

     - movieID
     - movieName
     - movieGenre
   - TVSeries

     - tvsID
     - tvsName
     - tvsGenre
   - ActorMovies

     - actorID (FK:Actor) (PK)
     - movieID (FK:Movies) (PK)
   - ActorTVSeries

     - actorID (FK:Actor) (PK)
     - tvsID (FK:TVSeries) (PK)

Here as we added ActorMovies and ActorTVSeries, we need not to repeat inoformation. But I do not know **how to ensure every movie or tv series will have an actor** as they are in different table. I also want to know weak and strong entities. Please help me.

Comment: This HTML tagging is a turn-off. Reformât reasonably.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Before posting, you are expected to have ***researched your issue and made a good attempt to come up with a solution yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and what you have done so far so we can help with that specific problem.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have searched on google and many other blogs but I was not able to clear my doubt. I have posted my approaches and points where I was troubling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enforce that in a relational database within the **schema** for the  following reason:

As a way to create RELATIONAL databases, you can create `CONSTRAINTS` that make sure that a record is validated against another table. This requires that the value against which something is validated already exists. You can't link an actor to a movie that doesn't exist: Both the actor record AND the movie record have to exist for this to happen. So it's possible (and required) to create a movie without an actor existing for it.

Your solution is NOT in the **schema**, but in the triggers AND **stored procedures** - using a transaction. You would need to provide BOTH an actor AND a movie to a stored procedure and it will create BOTH entries in the tables. It will have to be very smart and NOT recreate an actor record if one exists. It will have to re-use a movie if already created.

This whole logic has to checked against `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s to make sure every movie has at least one actor. This is through triggers.

I am a bit *lazy* and don't want to write the whole stored procedure for you at this point, if this answers your question. If you need help with the whole transaction, please let me know.

--- SUGGESTION ---

If this is a real project and not an exercise, I suggest the BUSINESS LOGIC (insure an actor exists) be enforced by your processing and display language. It's not a good idea to put business logic in the DB, very hard to maintain.

--- SIDE NOTE ---

You may want to add a `genre` table to validate the genres

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re over-complicating things. You’ve identified your entities:

- Actor
- Movie
- TV series

If an actor can act in both a movie and TV series, then there’s your relationships: you need tables joining actors to movies, and also actors to TV series. This will give you five tables:

- `actors`
- `movies`
- `tv_series`
- `actors_movies` (join table)
- `actors_tv_series` (join table)

Comment: I want to ensure that every movie has at least one actor. How that is ensured ?

Comment: You can’t do this with a relational database. You need to _create_ the movie before you can assign actors to it, so a movie’s going to have no actors in that state. Enforcing a number of related entities is an application concern.